# pyspark equivalent of pd.offsets.MontEnd(x)

Tags: pandas, pyspark

In pandas there is the function pd.offsets.MonthEnd(x), such that

Date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(x) returns the End of the month, x months after Date.

```
pd.to_datetime('2010-01-15') + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(3) = Timestamp('2010-03-31 00:00:00')
```

I am aware of the function `last_day(Date)` in pyspark. However, this does not take an offset argument, but simmply returns the end of the month. In which way do I retrieve similar behaviour of pd.offsets.MonthEnd(x) in pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `last_day` with [add_months](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.add_months.html):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df \
    .withColumn('add_months', F.add_months('my_timestamp', 3)) \
    .withColumn('result', F.last_day('add_months')) \
    .show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used it, but switched around the order of the operations because not all the months have the same amount of days.

Comment: good catch, I reverted this in answer as well